# Is there a way to write Objective-C with no-exception style?

Tags: objective-c, exception

Unlike returning values indicating errors in conventional C functions, many functions or methods in Objective-C may trigger exception instead. For example, `[NSString alloc]` will trigger an exception if it is running out of memory, while `malloc` will return a null pointer indicating failure.

Is there any way to write Objective-C code in such a no-exception way? For example, can I make `[NSString alloc]` return `nil` instead of throwing an exception, when it fails to allocate memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Objective-C assumes it will not run out of memory in most cases, and that if memory is exhausted, there is no reasonable way to recover and the program should abort. If you have a platform where memory exhaustion would be expected and recoverable, then you should not be using ObjC.

Many modern kernels, including Darwin, support over-commiting memory, so even malloc may not give you an error. Outside of embedded platforms, we generally assume that "small" (less than a megabyte) allocations will always succeed.

https://serverfault.com/questions/852059/does-darwin-macos-kernel-do-memory-overcommit

To the more general question about other assertion failures, no. Things that raise assertions or throw exceptions in ObjC are considered programming errors, and there is no way to recover from them. ObjC exceptions can be caught, but even those cannot be recovered. You can just do a little work before finishing the crash. (The rules are slightly different in ObjC++, but the general answer is the same. You cannot avoid all kinds of crashes.)